How to modify tflite model?
Although many model have sigmoid layer, the embedded system sometimes not supported this layer.
So, I want to remove this layer and then call this in my codes.
Could you tell me solution if you know that?
The example is normal mobilenetv1 had the softmax in last layer.
I use the API like the next
tflite_support.metadata.get_metadata_buffer(
    model_buf
)

I remove the softmax layer's buffer and then add Input layer, however it is not done.
If there is a better way, could you share it?
